# How to make transition smooth?

Tags: css

I am trying to create two containers which will be placed at the same position. When I mouse hover on top one that should affected with some transition and bottom/second div content should display. I tried this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjyz/1/)

Everything is fine.But it is giving some flicker effect when i mouse hover on it.
How to make it smooth transition? 
I am using following snippet for transition effect

```
.box:hover{
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin:bottom right;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use CSS [`transition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) property to make the animation smoother

```
.box {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    background:indianred;
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:40%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjyz/5/)

---

Note: You are using `-webkit` specific proprietary property, so inorder to make it cross browser compatible, use

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjyz/7/)

```
.box {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    background:indianred;
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:40%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.box1 {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:40%;
    z-index:-100;
}
.box:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin:bottom right;
     -moz-transform: rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    -moz-transform-origin:bottom right;
     transform: rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    transform-origin:bottom right;
}
```

---

Well, you asked for a solution in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173776/how-to-make-transition-smooth/22173881#comment33654731_22173881) and I provided a solution for that as well..

```
<div class='box1'>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <p class="innerText">This is content</p>
</div>

.box {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    background:indianred;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.box1 {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    left:40%;
    z-index:-100;
}
.box1:hover .box {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin:bottom right;
     -moz-transform: rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    -moz-transform-origin:bottom right;
     transform: rotate(100deg) scale(1);
    transform-origin:bottom right;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zdjyz/8/)

---

The difference between my code and your code is that first, you missed a `position: relative;` container around an element having `position: absolute;` which will always bring you undesired results.

Second mistake was the markup, if you are looking to hide an element, you should nest an overlaying element rather than placing it outside the element you want to hide.

So in my example, I shifted the overlaying element in the `div`, and the main part comes here, you used `:hover` on the same element you were transforming, and thus it was collapsing for no reason, instead, in my selector, I am triggering the animation on `:hover` of the parent element, and not the element it self which is to be transformed.

Comment: This is great. but I dont want to move my top div until i completely lost focus on my inner div? How to do it?

Comment: If i mouse over on my top div (which is having red color) it is moving. This is fine. After this effect if I mouse over on my Inner div the top div is coming to original state. I dont want to move the top div to original state until i completely lost the focus on the inner div.

Comment: This is awesome... can you please explain me?

Comment: @Mihir first of all always use `position: relative;` wrapper element when you use absolute for child, secondly, your markup and selectors were redundant, you were triggering hover on the same box which was modifying it self, result, it was collapsing again and again, I will provide you nice detailed explanation in an hour, as am at the office, so give me some time :)

Comment: @Alien, the strange thing is if i copy your css and the html and paste into my html file it is not working.. I am using html5 compliant only. Any idea?